# How automatically getting token in Postman

Tags: rest, postman, web-api-testing

I use the Postman desktop app for web API testing. I have a lot of controllers and for each need a token. First I get `Bearer token` and then copy it to other requests. This token have limit time. Can I get token automatically and then automatically set it to all others requests ?

Comment: https://liftcodeplay.com/2018/03/18/how-to-automatically-set-a-bearer-token-for-your-postman-requests/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ok, I just used Environments in postman.

1 - create new Environment with token.
[image]

2 - add test after auth request  like this :

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var token = jsonData._token;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", token);
```

3 - just set `{{token}}`

[image]

And of course you can set token before request if you use `Pre-request Script` in one of requests.

Comment: similar solution detailed here https://ppolyzos.com/2016/11/20/how-to-update-environment-variables-based-on-a-response-in-postman/

Answer (score 3):

**Following steps:**

**1. Create an environment on the Postman. Example: test_env**

**2. Create an environment variable. Example: jwtToken**

**3. Select the environment and go to the token API**

**4. Set Content-Type as application/json in Headers**

**5. goto the Tests option in Postman and write the script:**

```
if(pm.response.code === 200) {
    var my_token_response = JSON.parse(responseBody); 
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("jwtToken", "Bearer "+my_token_response.access);
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Write below code in tests tab in postman for your login request.

```
if(pm.response.code === 200) {
    pm.environment.set('authToken', pm.response.json().token)
}
```

Then edit your collection and set your `env` `authToken` inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can save and re-use the token's using the Token Name from Postman. You can select it from the available token list.

One of the many cases are.

1. Request for a refresh token using the credentials
2. Use the refresh token to get an access token
3. Use the access token to authenticate the API.

The step 1 sometimes requires us to login to an interface of the API provider and get an authentication code to our callback url. Some API provider's allow us to override this by providing the client_secret key and the client_id as an authorization header and the refresh token as the request parameters and by setting prompt as none.
From the documentation.

> prompt (optional)
>       none no UI will be shown during the request. If this is not possible (e.g. because the user has to sign in or consent) an error is returned.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/authorization.html

All you need to know about the identity servers are here.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/