# how to set token automatically in postman

Tags: api, postman

Want to set token automatically in postman. On a login Api call set token in postman automatically.
want to clear then postman variable and set new token given by as Api response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How automatically getting token in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907041/how-automatically-getting-token-in-postman)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the token variable in collection ver in postman.
2. write the given code in api test part

```
pm.collectionVariables.unset("<token _name>");
pm.collectionVariables.set("<token_name>", pm.response.text());
```

3. run api